# Sum particular column from csv file

Tags: php, arrays, csv, sum

I am reading data from file and displaying array like below code :

```
if (($fp = fopen("test.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {     
    $count = 0;
    while(($row = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE)
    {  
        $row = explode("|",$row[0]);
        foreach($row as &$el)
        {
            $el=trim($el);      
        }
        $count++;
        $tot = array_sum(array_column($row,2));
        echo "<pre>";print_r($row); 
        if($count>3)
        {
            break;  
        }
        echo "Coumt :".$tot;    
    }
    echo "Coumt :".$tot;
    fclose($fp);
}
```

**Test.txt file data :**

```
005-4410040      |BIRM| 0 
005-4410040      |CHI | 450
005-4410040      |CIN | 144
```

I want total sum of 2nd index of the array it means `320 + 450 + 144` in separate varriable.

How can I achieve this? I already tried `array_column()`, but its not working.

**Update: What I have tried:**

```
$sum = array_sum(array_column($row,$row['2']));
```

Comment: Read the documentation about `array_column()`. You want to pass `2` as second parameter for the 2 column.

Comment: write only '2' not $row[2]

Comment: What kind of array is this ? can you post your array assigning to variable

Comment: If you want to add the values of index 2, then do the following. I assume that your array variable is $data. Then  $sum = array_sum(array_column($data,2));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that using `array_column()` and `array_sum()` like this

```
$row = [
        ['005-4410040','BIRM',1],
        ['005-4410040','CHI',2],
        ['005-4410040','CIN',3]
    ];

$tot = array_sum(array_column($row, 2));
```

RESULT

```
6
```

#### After code added to the question:

You are not understanding [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) correctly, it gets one line at a time. So each call to fgetcsv return one line from the file which you explode into $row

All you need to do is accumulate `$row[2]` as you process over the lines of the file.

```
if (($fp = fopen("test.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {       
    $count = 0;
    $tot = 0;

    while(($row = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $row = explode("|",$row[0]);
        $count++;
        // I see one line with no value so to be safe
        $tot += $row[2] != '' ? $row[2] : 0;

        if($count>3) {
            break;  
        }
        echo "Coumt : $tot";  
    }

    echo "Coumt : $tot";
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling wrong sequence

```
$arr=array(array
(
     0  => "005-4410040",
     1  => "BIRM",
     2  => 320
),
array
(
     0  => "005-4410040",
     1  => "CHI",
     2  => 450
),
array
(
     0  => "005-4410040",
     1  => "CIN",
     2  => 144
));
echo (array_sum(array_column($arr, 2)));
```